# FIFO Communication between 2 different applications in C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, fifo, mkfifo

I have been trying to write a mechanism for communication between 2 different applications, one called server and the other client, that I launch separately in 2 terminals. I decided on using FIFO files, and the problem that I have encountered is that I write some text from the client app in the FIFO, and when I'm trying to transmit that data from the client to the server, the server process receives apparently nothing, and thus stopping everything.
The client app

```
char comanda[256], optiuni[256], inutil[5];
char raspuns[512];
char * fisierFifoScriere = "/home/cosmin/Documents/theFifoFile1";
char * fisierFifoCitire = "/home/cosmin/Documents/theFifoFile2";
FILE * scriere;
FILE * citire;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    //Aici initializam file descriptorii necesari
    scriere = fopen(fisierFifoScriere, "w");
    if(scriere == NULL){
        perror("Eroare la deschiderea fisierului: ");           
        return 1;
    }
    
    citire = fopen(fisierFifoCitire, "r");
    if(citire == NULL){
        perror("Eroare la deschiderea fisierului: ");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while(1){
    //Partea de citire de la utilizator si de trimitere a comenzii
        scanf("%s", comanda);
        if(strcmp(comanda, "login") == 0){
            scanf("%s %s", inutil, optiuni);
            fprintf(scriere, "%s %s", comanda, optiuni);
        }
        else if(strcmp(comanda, "get-proc-info") == 0){
            scanf("%s %s", inutil, optiuni);
            fprintf(scriere, "%s %s", comanda, optiuni);
        }
        else if(strcmp(comanda, "get-logged-users") == 0){
            fprintf(scriere, "%s", comanda);
        }
        else if(strcmp(comanda, "logout") == 0){
            fprintf(scriere, "%s", comanda);
        }
        else if(strcmp(comanda, "quit") == 0){
            fprintf(scriere, "%s", comanda);
        }
        else{
            printf("%s\n", "Command unkown. Please try again!");
        }
        //fflush(scriere);
    //Partea de primire a raspunsului de la server
        while(fgets(raspuns, sizeof(raspuns)+1, citire)){
            printf("%s\n", raspuns);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The server app

```
char comandaDeCitit[256];
char raspuns[256];
FILE * scriere; //scriere va fi file descriptorul pentru fifo ul folosit in trimiterea raspunsurilor catre client
FILE * citire;  //citire va fi file descriptorul pentru fifo ul folosit in citirea de la client
char * fisierFifoCitire = "/home/cosmin/Documents/theFifoFile1";
char * fisierFifoScriere = "/home/cosmin/Documents/theFifoFile2";

bool loggedUser = false;
char UserName[25];

pid_t pid;
int rv;

int main(){
    mkfifo(fisierFifoCitire, 0666);
    mkfifo(fisierFifoScriere, 0666);
    //Aici deschidem un descriptor de citire, pentru a putea obtine comanda de la client.
    citire = fopen(fisierFifoCitire, "r");
    if(citire == NULL){
            perror("Eroare la deschiderea fisierului: ");
            return 1;
    }
    //Aici deschidem un descriptor de scriere, pentru a trimite raspunsul catre client.
    scriere = fopen(fisierFifoScriere, "w");
    if(citire == NULL){
            perror("Eroare la deschiderea fisierului: ");
            return 1;
    }
    //In aceasta bucla while vom citi continuu din fisierul de citire pana cand primim o comanda la care putem raspunde, iar atunci vom trece la partea de scriere
    //Sau cel putin acesta este planul :)
    while(1){
        //Partea de citire
        fscanf(citire, "%s", comandaDeCitit);
        //Partea de scriere
        if (strcmp(comandaDeCitit, "login") == 0){
            fprintf(scriere, "%s ", "test");
            fflush(scriere);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try calling `fflush`

Comment: I tried adding fflush and the result hasn't changed, it still does not communicate with the server process.